# Understanding Cook's Distance

Tags: statistics, regression-analysis

Does Cooks Distance tell us how much the **estimated parameter values** change when the i<sup>th</sup> observation is removed or how much the **fitted values** change when the i<sup>th</sup> observation is removed?

I'm being told both statements are true given that the fitted values are a function of the parameter values but not sure this statement 100% adds up.

Any help in understanding would be appreciated.

Comment: This belongs on CrossValidated.SE